# how to solve the error of DBeaver database?

Tags: dbeaver

I used DBeaver (database management tools) and faced this type of error

[image]

Comment: Hi. Could you edit your post to include the error message from the image as text. Further more, we cannot help you unless you provide a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that is the shorthest code possible to reproduce your error. Finally, keep in mind that stackoverflow is about programming questions, so your question might be off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to connect to a MySQL instance over SSH. Most likely issue is that the remote server isn't accepting SSH connections. If you try the following at a command line, can you establish a connection? (Bash if you're using Linux, putty if you're on Windows)

```
ssh <user>@<remotehost>
```

Also it's important to mention that you probably have two sets of credentials you're using here. The credentials to connect to the SSH server are not necessarily the same as the credentials to connect to the MySQL database.